# How to pass implemented class object as parameter in API routes

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi

My codebase looks like below

```
.
└── myfolder/
    └── mock/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── main.py
        └── mock_tasks.py
    └── common/
        ├── __init__.py
        └── db.py
        └── common_tasks.py
        └── routers
            └── myroute.py
            └── __init__.py
```

This is fastAPi application , I start the application by going inside `mock` and run the `main.py`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from common.db import create_db_and_tables
from common.routers import myroute


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(myroute.router)


@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    create_db_and_tables()
```

Then the control goes to `myroute` based on the `API` , which looks like below

```
from common_tasks import BaseTasks
base_tasks = BaseTasks("")
@router.post("/", response_model=Mymodel)
async def create(
    ...
):
    ...

    background_tasks.add_task(
        base_tasks.run, {some_data}
    )


    return some_data
```

Now the `BaseTasks` is an abstract class and implemented in `mock`. `BaseTasks` looks like below

```
@dataclass
class BaseTasks(abc.ABC):
    key: str
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self): pass
```

And the implementation in `mock` looks like below

```
from common.common_tasks import BaseTasks

@dataclass
class MockTasks(BaseTasks):
    key: str

    def run(self):
        <<actual implementation>>
```

Now I am having confusion when running `mock` , how to pass the `MockTasks` object in my `myroute.router` , so that it knows exactly which implementation of task to call.

Also please suggest if any design change make more sense to address this.

Comment: Do you want your `create()` API to use `MockTasks.run()` method?

Comment: Yes , but there can be `MockTasks2` , `MockTasks3` in future.

Comment: So on what basis do you decide which one to use? If it's the same API going to use either of them, then there needs to be a parameter passed to the API to tell which task to use.

Comment: @RohitJain exactly thats what I want , but I am little confused how to do that.  `base_tasks.run, {some_data}` in `BaseTasks` should be parameterized. I am also open to any deisgn change if that addresses the problem better .

Comment: You need to pass a parameter to the API (query parameter, or request body), and based on that parameter create the object of task inside the API itself. Get rid of `base_task` object created outside the API method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create object of `BaseTasks` outside the API. What you want is to create appropriate implementation class object created based on certain parameter passed to the API:

```
from common_tasks import BaseTasks
from task_factory import TaskFactory

# You don't need this object here
# base_tasks = BaseTasks("")

@router.post("/", response_model=Mymodel)
async def create(
    task_schema: TaskSchema   # Assuming you've a Model defined for request body
):
    # The below logic can be anything
    task = TaskFactory.get_task(task_schema.name)

    background_tasks.add_task(
        task.run, {some_data}
    )

    return some_data
```

Comment: The only thing here is, I have to keep updating the task conditions to accommodate any new addition . I was thinking if there is a way to `bootstrap` route with a `task` object and use the same

Comment: You'll need to have a TaskFactory, which will give you whatever task you want, and this API will be unchanged then. You can't bootstrap route with specific task object, because you want same API to work on multiple tasks.